# Install R 3+ on Redhat 6.3

Tags: r, expect, redhat

I want to install R on my Red hat cluster which has the version below:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)
```

When I went to R's homepage and this is what in their [repository](http://rweb.quant.ku.edu/cran/):

[image]

I am wondering there is only redhat version 4 and 5 there and I don't know which version will best fit my operating system.

[Texinfo Problem Goes Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642246/install-r-on-redhat-6-requires-texinfo-text)

Since I have asked more than 6 questions today. Stackoverflow doesn't like me to ask more questions. So I will put the following questions into this question, sorry about that.

Hi, I was trying to use Expect to automatically log into a remote server and install R. 
When I install R, they came up with all kinds of prompts asking 'The package will take xx MB Is that OK with you'?

The command to install:

```
su -c 'yum install R R-core R-core-devel R-devel'
```

You need to type in Yes for a few times to finish the installation.

My question is:

1. Is there a flag for yum install that you can tell the machine to install everything I want you to install. Don't ask me. So I can install those four packages without any prompt.
2. If that is hard to install in the 'quiet mode', how to write a while loop in Expect so it will send the Y automatically:

   ```
   Pseudo Code Not Working!
   send -- "sudo su -c yum install ...."
   while ("Expect '*Is it OK [Y/N]*'"){
   send 'Y\r'
   # if (expect 'user$')
   {break}
   }
   ```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely due to there being R RPMs in the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repos for RHEL6. You can find out more about EPEL on the [Fedora website](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

You need to configure `yum` to use EPEL. The easiest way to do this is to install the `epel-release` package for your platform, eg

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm'
```

or

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm'
```

for example. The you can use `yum` to install R, e.g. you will probably want

```
su -c 'yum install R R-core R-core-devel R-devel'
```

so that you pull in the packages needed to build other add-on packages as most CRAN package are not in EPEL.

At the moment, the latest version of R in EPEL is 3.0.1, so one patch release point behind the latest version 3.0.2.

Comment: I am testing it on AWS right now, which reach back to you if I have any problem.

Comment: Hi Gavin, I just noticed that the R is actually partially installed... actually only R-core has been installed successfully. When I tried to install R, R-core-devel and R-devel, it tells me Requires: texinfo-tex, do you know how to get around it?