# Install R on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.2 (Santiago)

Tags: r, installation, redhat, rpm

I referred [Install R 3+ on Redhat 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277953/install-r-3-on-redhat-6-3) for installing R on my system which is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.2 (Santiago)` But getting the errors:

```
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: pcre-devel
Error: Package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libtk8.5.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: texinfo-tex
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tk-devel
Error: Package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(latex)
Error: Package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(dvips)
Error: Package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(latex)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tcl-devel
```

When I try to install a package mentioned in the error, it gives error showing another package from same list, and ultimately forms a cycle.

The whole log is:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libRmath-devel = 3.0.2-1.el6 for package: R-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: R-java = 3.0.2-1.el6 for package: R-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: tex(latex) for package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tex(dvips) for package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtk8.5.so()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package R-core-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: tk-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: texinfo-tex for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tex(latex) for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tcl-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pcre-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package R-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: R-java-devel = 3.0.2-1.el6 for package: R-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: tex(latex) for package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tex(dvips) for package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtk8.5.so()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package R-core-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: tk-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: texinfo-tex for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tex(latex) for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tcl-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pcre-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package R-java.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package R-java-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libRmath-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libRmath = 3.0.2-1.el6 for package: libRmath-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: tex(latex) for package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tex(dvips) for package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtk8.5.so()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package R-core-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: tk-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: texinfo-tex for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tex(latex) for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tcl-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pcre-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package libRmath.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: pcre-devel
Error: Package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libtk8.5.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: texinfo-tex
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tk-devel
Error: Package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(latex)
Error: Package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(dvips)
Error: Package: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(latex)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tcl-devel
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 9 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
dvd+rw-tools-7.1-5.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with dvd+rw-tools-7.1-5blocks.el6.x86_64
gvfs-1.4.3-15.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with gvfs-1.4.3-12.el6.x86_64
gvfs-afc-1.4.3-15.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with gvfs-afc-1.4.3-12.el6.x86_64
gvfs-archive-1.4.3-15.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with gvfs-archive-1.4.3-12.el6.x86_64
gvfs-devel-1.4.3-15.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with gvfs-devel-1.4.3-12.el6.x86_64
gvfs-fuse-1.4.3-15.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with gvfs-fuse-1.4.3-12.el6.x86_64
gvfs-gphoto2-1.4.3-15.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with gvfs-gphoto2-1.4.3-12.el6.x86_64
gvfs-obexftp-1.4.3-15.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with gvfs-obexftp-1.4.3-12.el6.x86_64
gvfs-smb-1.4.3-15.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with gvfs-smb-1.4.3-12.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: I feel for you, having to occasionally deal with this for CentOS machines at work (where we also deploy Ubuntu which are a complete breeze in comparison).  But this all resolvable via EPEL etc -- maybe ask on the r-sig-fedora list?  But if you can, consider a switch to Ubuntu or Debian...